# Channels in NixOS with VirtualBox

Tags: nixos

`nix-channel --list` gives no output in my fresh NixOS installation. I used a VirtualBox appliance from https://nixos.org/nixos/download.html.

1. Do I need to subscribe to a channel?
2. Why aren't there any channels visible in the VirtualBox installation?
3. I can install packages just fine, don't I need a channel for that?

I am a NixOS beginner and still trying to grasp the basic concepts.

edit: I was running `nix-channel --list` with user permissions, whereas `sudo nix-channel --list` listed a channel as expected...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `nix-channel --list` as non-root user on a fresh installation of NixOS there will be no output.
That's because root's default channel (nixos) is also available for users. So `nix-env` called by user will use it.
So you can update both the system profile and user's pkgs (installed via `nix-env -i`).

Answer (score 1):

You need a binary channel to install software in binary form, instead of building it from source.

It seems channels are not added in VB appliance.

See http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/sec-upgrading.html how to add one.

Comment: New packages are downloading from cache.nixos though. It seems like the image comes with a fixed nixpkgs and I need a channel if I want to update the nixpkgs (if that makes sense).